# GAE 1 Mb Entity Limit

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a small dataset, its around 2000 rows, and the Entity only has 4 String fields and a Long id. When I populate the database run locally there is no problems, but when I run it on appengine i only get 867 records into the database before I hit the 1 Mb limit.

what am i missing?

he GAE documentation states:

" App Engine Datastore uses a distributed architecture to automatically manage scaling to very large data sets "

is there a discussion somewhere on how to get around this severe limitation?

Comment: do you have bloating indexes? 1MB _per entity_ is no way severe

Comment: Can you show us your tables and indexes?

Comment: i just went into the admin panel and it says i have no indexes

Comment: so you are storing large (~250k) pieces of text in the database? In this case you should look into the alternatives (blobstore)

Comment: i have a bunch of static methods and static variables in the Entity class, my understanding of java is that should not be a problem, could that bloat the record size ?

Comment: no all the text is less than 100 characters

Comment: then I can't see how you hit the 1MB per entity limit.

Comment: Isn't that 1MB per entity _group_?

Comment: i feel like it must be a settings issue, because whenever i add the 867 records it also chews up a large percentage (over 15 percent) of my 50000 daily quota for database writes, but then when i look at the db management panel there is only the 867 records there, i do issue a delete * each time i upload the new records

Comment: screams to me "bloated indexes". Are you sure you have none, including the implicit one-column indexes?

Comment: ok well if there are implicit indexes they are not showing up in the management panel, here is a link to my persisence.xml

Comment: https://github.com/semisided1/topnotchgames/tree/master/src/META-INF

Comment: my datastore-indexes-auto.xml file only has an empty root element <datastore-indexes />

Comment: @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")

Comment: i will add the extension annotation to all my fields and see if that helps tomorrow, i am at quota for writes, i can not seem to get any testing done without hitting quota

Comment: @JanDvorak No. The 1MB limit is per entity, not per entity group.

Comment: well i added the annotation and had some different results, but still had some problems getting all my records into the database, i ended up ditching jpa altogether and using datastore api with a large Text field

Answer (score 0):

I seems you put all your data into one entity instead of using 1 entity per "row". What data access API do you use? Sounds like low-level API, which is good. Are sure you are not putting all your entities inside one large parent entity? Or are you using really large strings? Use the the datastore viewer in the appspot console to see your current data (the parts that got written to datastore before the error). It should be easy for you to spot anomalies there.